# Track number of hits for different dimension values, triggered by events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an area on my site where there are some dropdowns that filter a list of items based on what is selected. There is also a search bar that will search the list. What I would like to do is have a Custom Report in GA that tracks how many times each option from the dropdowns are selected, as well as what search terms people are entering.

My question, is how do I properly configure the event / dimensions / metrics to report on this data? I imagine a report like this:

- Composer     Hits
- Mozart       102
- Beethoven    83
- Stravinski   72

So far I am collecting the items in custom dimensions (one per dropdown), which are triggered by an event, like this (angular / typescript):

```
    (window as any).dataLayer.push({
                    'event': 'filter-guest-artist',
                    'GuestArtist': this.currentComposer
                });
```

The tags are firing correctly in the GTM debugger, but my issue is I'm not sure if I should use a custom metric or event to track the hits. Right now in my custom report there's no data because I don't have a proper metric to track by. I've used custom dimensions in a similar way but they were collected on Page View and I used the Page View as my metric, but that isn't applicable here since these are triggered by events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would go with an event. As I can infer from your description, the dropdown is used to filter the results. Every time a user selects one of your dropdown values and filters the results, fire an event with event label as the name of the filter. For example

- event category: {{title of the list}}
- event action: 'filter'
- event label: {{name
  of the selected item}}

Then I could easily answer my question through the Analytics interface on the events section. Filter by event action == 'filter' and as the event label as a dimension. The metrics TotalEvents and UniqueEvents will give you the insights you require.

For the search terms that users type on your page you can use the build in search term report that requires some small configuration. [See more here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en)

If cannot implement that, I would advise you use another custom event with the structure ase below

- event category: {{title of the list}}
- event action: 'search'
- event label: {{search tem}}

This way you would see the search terms as event labels in your event report after you apply the correct filters.